# Communication between SpriteView and normal View

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, spriteview

I am currently working on a project, where I use SpriteView to display game content and normal Views to display menus and navigation in general. I am able to create and load SpriteViews when pressing buttons in the normal view but the communication does not work the other way. I want to be able to change State variables in the parent View-Element by using buttons/SKShapeNodes of the child SpriteView-Element.

I tried Binding variables between the two instances and using callback-functions. But I wasn't able to change any content in the View-Element.

Is there a simple and effective way to send requests from a child-SpriteView to the parent-View ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ObservableObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject) - [`@Published`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published) pattern for this.

Make your `GameScene` conform to the `ObservableObject` protocol and publish the properties that you are interested to send the values of into the SwiftUI views, something like this:

```swift
class GameScene: SKScene, ObservableObject {
    @Published var updates = 0
    @Published var isPressed = false
    // ...
}
```

Then, in your SwiftUI view, use a [`@StateObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject) property (or an [`@ObservedObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/observedobject) or an [`@EnvironmentObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject)) to store the `GameScene` instance. You can then use the `GameScene`'s published properties in your SwiftUI view:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var scene: GameScene = {
        let scene = GameScene()
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 400)
        return scene
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            SpriteView(scene: scene).ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Text("Updates from SKScene: \(scene.updates)")
                if scene.isPressed {
                    Text("isPressed is true inside GameScene")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you "press buttons in the normal view", change the value of the published properties, and they will change the SwiftUI views that uses them.